# OpenCV MatchTemplate on GPU

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

In my C# project I need fast template matching algorithm. What I have now is OpenCV implementation. The simplified code is:

```
 using OpenCvSharp;
 using OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus;
 // ...

 var image = new Mat("Image.png");
 var template = new Mat("Template.png");

 double minVal, maxVal;
 Point minLoc, maxLoc;
 var result = image.MatchTemplate(template, MatchTemplateMethod.CCoeffNormed);
 result.MinMaxLoc(out minVal, out maxVal, out minLoc, out maxLoc);
 Console.WriteLine("maxLoc: {0}, maxVal: {1}", maxLoc, maxVal);
```

I'd like to do the same calculations on GPU to speed them up significantly, but cannot find an example of how to do that. The example on [github](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/sample/CStyleSamplesCS/Samples/GpuTest.cs) is commented out and doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to port OpenCV's `matchTemplate()` function to the GPU before.

They actually give the equations in [their documentation for the method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate). This is called **"normalized cross-correlation."**

[image]

The naive approach is to simply port that to the GPU (I did it as a pixel shader).  It turned out slower than OpenCV's CPU method.  Why?  They are actually using a method called **"fast normalized cross-correlation"** as outlined in [this paper](http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.html) by J.P Lewis from ILM.

The trick is to do the correlation in the frequency domain and take advantage of the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Convolution_theorem): a point-wise multiplication in the frequency domain is equivalent to a convolution in the spatial domain.  For us that means the time complexity is greatly reduced, and all we have to add is an FFT.